# Multiple projects in one visual studio solution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am asp.net MVC beginner and I have just created new solution. What I have noticed is that there is now an option of adding two projects under the same solution, and that is something that is new to me.

What is a main purpose that one should add multiple project under same solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution can hold multiple projects that are related and logically grouped together. For example, a solution may contain two web site projects (a user site and an administration site) and then also a class library project that they both share which contains common database access code or business logic.

Comment: so basically instead of having multiple visual studio instances and common repository, it is now possible to put connected projects in the same solution and should build project or solution accordingly...

Comment: Yes. These makes it much easier to manage dependencies between the projects.

Answer (score 1):

Usually we separate our code into multiple projects for easier maintenance in future. On an high level we make separate Class libraries for Data Access, Domain Models, Business Logic. Web project for Front end UI. This way we are physically separating code, that it increases re-usability. Say in future you want to re-use your Data Access components, then build that class library and take the DLL and use it in other projects.

Also in future if you want to replace a certain layer, then you can simply decouple it and change, without changing any other components of code.

This physical segregation of code with Logical [Dependency Injection](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/contact-manager/iteration-4-make-the-application-loosely-coupled-cs) would give you more cleaner, easy to maintain, re-usable, loosely coupled systems